# How do I switch between Kivy screens on different .py files

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy

I have currently got 3 python files. 1 which is where all the main initialisation methods happen, one for a sign in page and one for a sign up page. I cannot get the sign up button on the login page to take me to the sign up page however. Please can someone help. I have tried to change the sm.current inside of the login.py file but that did not work either.

Here is the main.py file:

```py
# Fitness App Main Code
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from LogInWindow import LogInWindow  # importing the class from Login.py
from SignUpWindow import SignUpWindow


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):  # creating a class that deals with screen management
    pass


sm = WindowManager()  # setting a variable to the window manager class

screens = [LogInWindow(name="Login_window"), SignUpWindow(name="Signup_window")]  # setting an array of lists
for screen in screens:  # going through all of the screens
    sm.add_widget(screen)  # adding the screen widget to each

sm.current = "Login_window"  # setting current window to login


class FitnessApp(App):  # the class that runs the app
    def build(self):
        App.title = "Fitness App"  # setting the app title
        Window.size = (1080, 720)  # setting window size
        return sm  # running the app by returning the current window


if __name__ == '__main__':  # The value of __name__ attribute is set to “__main__” when module is run as main program
    FitnessApp = FitnessApp()
    FitnessApp.run()
```

Here is the login.py file

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from database import get_details


def switch_to_signup():
    from main import sm
    sm.current_screen = "Signup_window"


class LogInWindow(Screen):  # creating LogInWindow class
    kv = Builder.load_file("LogInWindow.kv")  # loading the kivy file which has all the

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):  # defining an init method
        super().__init__(**kwargs)  # giving the subclass the same parameter signature as the parent

    def validate_user(self):  # creating a function to validate the user
        username_input_kivy = self.ids.username_field  # setting the input to a variable
        password_input_kivy = self.ids.password_field  # setting the input to a variable
        info = self.ids.info  # setting the input to a variable

        username_input = username_input_kivy.text  # getting the text from an input and putting it into a variable
        password_input = password_input_kivy.text  # getting the text from an input and putting it into a variable

        if username_input == '' or password_input == '':  # checking if the fields are empty
            info.text = '[color=#FF0000]Username And / Or Password Required[/color]'  # red error message
        else:
            user_details = get_details(username_input)

            username = user_details[0]  # set the username to the 1st value
            users_password = user_details[1]  # set the password to the 2nd value

            if username_input == username and password_input == users_password:  # checking if they are correct
                info.text = '[color=#00FF00]Logged In successfully!!![/color]'  # green success message
            else:
                info.text = '[color=#FF0000]Invalid Username and/or Password[/color]'  # red error message
```

and here is the relevant kivy button:

```
            Button:
                text: "Don't have an account? Sign Up Here!"  ## setting the text to the sign up
                font_size:20  ## changing font size
                size_hint_y: None  ## setting size hint to none so it can be set to anything
                height: 60  ## setting height to 60
                background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)  ## setting background colour
                background_normal: ''  ## changing the background_normal to nothing
                on_release: root.switch_to_signup()  ##will change to put it to sign up screen
```

There is almost nothing in the signup.py file but I will include it incase that helps.

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen


class SignUpWindow(Screen):  # creating LogInWindow class
    kv = Builder.load_file("SignUpWindow.kv")  # loading the kivy file which has all the

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):  # defining an init method
        super().__init__(**kwargs)  # giving the subclass the same parameter signature as the parent
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `kv` file you can always access the `App` using the keyword `app`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords).

So, in your `kv`, change the `Button` to:

```
       Button:
            text: "Don't have an account? Sign Up Here!"  ## setting the text to the sign up
            font_size:20  ## changing font size
            size_hint_y: None  ## setting size hint to none so it can be set to anything
            height: 60  ## setting height to 60
            background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)  ## setting background colour
            background_normal: ''  ## changing the background_normal to nothing
            on_release: app.root.current = "Signup_window"  ##will change to put it to sign up screen
```

Of course, this assumes that the `name` of the `SignUpWindow` is "Signup_window".

Comment: Thank you very much. I forgot that i could do that and it worked perfectly. I’m relatively new to kivy but i’m picking it up fairly quickly! :)